# Bash incrementation breaking scripts

Tags: bash, increment

I'm having a weird issue incrementing a bash variable that seems
to be breaking after my first attempt at incremntation that I cannot
pin down, here is a sample of what I am doing and the debug output, 
anyone see any reason this should NOT work?

I am currently on `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex 
declare -i elem=0
echo $elem # 0
    (( elem++ )) # breaks
echo $elem # 1 but never encountered
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    (( elem++ ))
    echo $elem
done <"${1}" # foo\nbar\nbaz
```

Output

```
./incr.sh test
+ declare -i elem=0
+ echo 0
0
+ ((  elem++  ))
```

The weirdest part is by changing the initial incrementor to `(( elem+=1 ))`
the entire program increments correctly, this seems extremely buggy to the eye...

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex 
declare -i elem=0
echo $elem
    (( elem+=1 ))
echo $elem
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    (( elem++ ))
    echo $elem
done <"${1}" # foo\nbar\nbaz
```

Output

```
+ declare -i elem=0
+ echo 0
0
+ ((  elem+=1  ))
+ echo 1
1
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r line
+ ((  elem++  ))
+ echo 2
2
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r line
+ ((  elem++  ))
+ echo 3
3
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r line
+ ((  elem++  ))
+ echo 4
4
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r line
+ [[ -n '' ]]
```

Comment: Where is `filename=test` coming from? I don't see that in the script.

Comment: Sorry I changed the code to just use `$1` as the input file, if you look again I changed the input, sry I was using a older versions output

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://ideone.com/jm3CQR

Comment: Why did you delete your code? The question is nonsensical without the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -e` makes your script exit when any command returns failure.

`(( 0 ))`, and equivalently `elem=0; (( elem++ ))` returns failure.

Therefore, the script exits.

If you `set -e` and want to run commands whose status you don't care, about, you can use

```
(( elem++ )) || true
```

Comment: Awesome anwer, waiting to accept =) thank you, great catch, didn't see that

Comment: Why does `((elem++))` return failure?

Comment: because elem evaluates as bool(0) ;)

Comment: Another fix would be to use pre-increment `(( ++elem ))`, since this will evaluate to `1`?

Comment: @Barmar that happens to work in this case, but if `elem=-1` you're back to the same problem.